# No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/scope-manager@4.22.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

The below issue is occuring while creating new app or running npm install. Please help me to resolve the error.
I also tried the below command but error is same.

npm install -g create-react-ap

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/scope-manager@4.22.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-04T15_04_07_787Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo in your command.

The package you are trying to install is `create-react-app` instead of `create-react-ap`

Try `npm install -g create-react-app`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Today the same command worked fine without any change. It looks like npm issue fixed overnight

Answer (score 0):

```html
sidebar.component.ts************
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare const $: any;
declare interface RouteInfo {
    path: string;
    title: string;
    icon: string;
    class: string;
}
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
    { path: '/dashboard', title: 'Dashboard',  icon: 'dashboard', class: '' },
    { path: '/user-profile', title: 'User Profile',  icon:'person', class: '' },
    { path: '/table-list', title: 'Table List',  icon:'content_paste', class: '' },
    { path: '/typography', title: 'Typography',  icon:'library_books', class: '' },
    { path: '/icons', title: 'Icons',  icon:'bubble_chart', class: '' },
    { path: '/maps', title: 'Maps',  icon:'location_on', class: '' },
    { path: '/notifications', title: 'Notifications',  icon:'notifications', class: '' },
    { path: '/upgrade', title: 'Upgrade to PRO',  icon:'unarchive', class: 'active-pro' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  menuItems: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem);
  }
  isMobileMenu() {
      if ($(window).width() > 991) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  };
}

**************sidebar.component.html**************
<div class="logo">
    <a href="https://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text">
        <div class="logo-img">
            <img src="/assets/img/angular2-logo-red.png"/>
        </div>
        Creative Tim
    </a>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div *ngIf="isMobileMenu()">
    <form class="navbar-form">
      <span class="bmd-form-group">
        <div class="input-group no-border">
          <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
            <div class="ripple-container"></div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </span>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-mobile-menu">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                <p>
                    <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Stats</span>
                </p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                <span class="notification">5</span>
                <p>
                    <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Some Actions</span>
                </p>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mike John responded to your email</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">You have 5 new tasks</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">You're now friend with Andrew</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another Notification</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another One</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                <p>
                    <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Account</span>
                </p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
                <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>
                <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

***********components.module.ts************
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    FooterComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    FooterComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }

***********routing***********

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';

const routes: Routes =[
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }, {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
    }]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
       useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


***********app.component.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
********8navbar.component.html*********

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent  navbar-absolute fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">{{getTitle()}}</a>
        </div>
        <button mat-raised-button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="sidebarToggle()">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation">
            <form class="navbar-form">
                <div class="input-group no-border">
                    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                        <p>
                            <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Stats</span>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                        <span class="notification">5</span>
                        <p>
                            <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Some Actions</span>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Mike John responded to your email</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">You have 5 new tasks</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">You're now friend with Andrew</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Another Notification</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Another One</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        <p>
                            <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Account</span>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!--
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-absolute">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="sidebarToggle()">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">{{getTitle()}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                        <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                        <span class="notification">5</span>
                        <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Notifications</p>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Mike John responded to your email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">You have 5 new tasks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">You're now friend with Andrew</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another Notification</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another One</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                       <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                       <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Profile</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group form-black is-empty">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="material-input"></span>
                </div>
                <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i><div class="ripple-container"></div>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav> -->

*******navbar.component.ts****
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTES } from '../sidebar/sidebar.component';
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    private listTitles: any[];
    location: Location;
      mobile_menu_visible: any = 0;
    private toggleButton: any;
    private sidebarVisible: boolean;

    constructor(location: Location,  private element: ElementRef, private router: Router) {
      this.location = location;
          this.sidebarVisible = false;
    }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.listTitles = ROUTES.filter(listTitle => listTitle);
      const navbar: HTMLElement = this.element.nativeElement;
      this.toggleButton = navbar.getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggler')[0];
      this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        this.sidebarClose();
         var $layer: any = document.getElementsByClassName('close-layer')[0];
         if ($layer) {
           $layer.remove();
           this.mobile_menu_visible = 0;
         }
     });
    }

    sidebarOpen() {
        const toggleButton = this.toggleButton;
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        setTimeout(function(){
            toggleButton.classList.add('toggled');
        }, 500);

        body.classList.add('nav-open');

        this.sidebarVisible = true;
    };
    sidebarClose() {
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        this.toggleButton.classList.remove('toggled');
        this.sidebarVisible = false;
        body.classList.remove('nav-open');
    };
    sidebarToggle() {
        // const toggleButton = this.toggleButton;
        // const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var $toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggler')[0];

        if (this.sidebarVisible === false) {
            this.sidebarOpen();
        } else {
            this.sidebarClose();
        }
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

        if (this.mobile_menu_visible == 1) {
            // $('html').removeClass('nav-open');
            body.classList.remove('nav-open');
            if ($layer) {
                $layer.remove();
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                $toggle.classList.remove('toggled');
            }, 400);

            this.mobile_menu_visible = 0;
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $toggle.classList.add('toggled');
            }, 430);

            var $layer = document.createElement('div');
            $layer.setAttribute('class', 'close-layer');


            if (body.querySelectorAll('.main-panel')) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('main-panel')[0].appendChild($layer);
            }else if (body.classList.contains('off-canvas-sidebar')) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper-full-page')[0].appendChild($layer);
            }

            setTimeout(function() {
                $layer.classList.add('visible');
            }, 100);

            $layer.onclick = function() { //asign a function
              body.classList.remove('nav-open');
              this.mobile_menu_visible = 0;
              $layer.classList.remove('visible');
              setTimeout(function() {
                  $layer.remove();
                  $toggle.classList.remove('toggled');
              }, 400);
            }.bind(this);

            body.classList.add('nav-open');
            this.mobile_menu_visible = 1;

        }
    };

    getTitle(){
      var titlee = this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path());
      if(titlee.charAt(0) === '#'){
          titlee = titlee.slice( 1 );
      }

      for(var item = 0; item < this.listTitles.length; item++){
          if(this.listTitles[item].path === titlee){
              return this.listTitles[item].title;
          }
      }
      return 'Dashboard';
    }
}
```